# Подключение библиотеки. Использование точек останова в плагине Go для IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, golang, отладка, lib, golang-faq

Я создал проект в *IntelliJ IDEA* посредством плагина для golang. Есть package main, в котором импортируются различные иные пакеты.

```
import (
    "RF"
    "flag"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "depot"
    "info"
    "logger"
    "logic"
    "poly"
    "ranker"
    "revgeocoder"
    "search"
    "search/engine"
    "stat"
    "views"
    "fmt"
)
```

Они прекрасно подключаются, если прописать пути в `$GOPATH`. В Idea Intellij это делается так:

[image: Пути к пакетам]

Теперь, я хочу:

1. Собрать проект без предупреждений
2. Отладить проект

---

Начнём с первого пункта. Когда я говорю 'build', то выскакивает предупреждение: "Package is not specified"

[image: Package is not specified]

Если в поле Pakage добавить название пакета main, то предупреждение не уйдёт:

[image: Cannot find package <code>main</code>]

Как бороться с данной проблемой?

---

Пункт номер два. После сборки, которая проходит неожиданно успешно, оказывается, что часть пакетов, подключенных при помощи `$GOPATH` можно отлаживать, а часть -- нет. Например, файл пакета engine отлаживается хорошо. Данный пакет располагается по пути:

/home/INT.PV.KM/urvanov/hedgehogues/distr/mapsfullsearch/src/search/engine/engine.go

С другой стороны, войти в файл другого пакета я не могу. Данный пакет же располагается каталогом выше:

/home/INT.PV.KM/urvanov/hedgehogues/distr/mapsfullsearch/src/search/context.go

[image: Дерево каталогов]

Подскажите, с чем может быть связана данная проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ответ на первый вопроc

Проект в Go состоит из пакетов. Ничего кроме пакетов, собственно и не существует. Обычно все пакеты лежат в одной директории, которую можно мыслить как проект. Если существуют сторонние директории, то они мыслятся как библиотеки и указываются при помощи переменной окружения `$GOPATH`. В IDEA IntelliJ это легко делается при помощи следующих махинаций:

File->Settings:

[image: Указание пути к внешним пакетам]

В Go проекте есть два вида либ: проектные и глобальные. О них можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844770/3696633).

Во время сборки нужно указать, какой пакет мы хотим собрать, а все зависимости сами выстроятся. В моём проекте есть n пакетов. Например, я могу собрать пакет mapsfullsearch, могу собрать пакет mfsimporter, либо любой другой, в котором есть `func main() {/*...*/}`. Для сборки достаточно лишь указать соответствующую конфигурацию.

После этого все import`ы (если соответствующие пакеты существуют, разрешатся).

[image: Структура моего проекта]

Теперь о конфигурациях. Заходим Run -> Edit Configurations...

[image: Настройка конфигурации]

Name: название скомпиленного файла. 
Run kind: можно собирать один файл или целый пакет.
Package: название пакета, который совпадает с названием директории, в которой находится `main()`. В IDEA IntelliJ прикручен список выпадающих пакетов. Он появляется, если начать писать его название.
Output directory: директория, в которую пометится бинарник
Environments: переменные окружения
Go Tool argumetns: аргументы компилятора
Program argumetns: аргументы, которые передаются в программу

Подробнее о конфигах можно почитать [тут](https://rootpd.com/2016/02/04/setting-up-intellij-idea-for-your-first-golang-project/).

### Ответ на второй вопроc

Проблема заключается в том, что IDEA плохо задаёт путь к файлам. В том случае, о котором я говорил в своём вопросе, проблема была связана с тем, что путь к библиотекам указывался через домашнюю директорию, которая обозначается `~`, которую, к слову IDEA не воспринимает. Воспроизвести эту проблему у меня не получилось. Хотя до того момента, пока я не положил проект в корень файловой системы, у меня ничего не работало.

### Комментарий

IDEA -- это ещё слегка сыроватый продукт, где фигурируют баги. Например, есть баг с проблемой редактирования горячих клавиш. Так, скажем, хочется поменять сборку и запуск проекта на ctrl+R. Идём Settings->Keymap, где ищем соответствующую клавишу и меняем её на нужную комбинацию. После того, как произойдёт перезапуск IDEA Intellij, либо смена фокуса на другое приложение и возврат его обратно, клавиша перестанет работать. То же самое относится ко всем остальным горячим клавишам. Для того, чтобы этот баг поправить, необходимо ещё раз пройти в Keymap и попробовать что-нибудь найти в поиске. После этого всё должно встать на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

В Package нужно указывать путь к вашему проекту из GOPATH вашего проекта.
Допустим: github.com/user/helloWorld
Это нужно для того, чтобы собирался не единичный файл а пакет.